# Livestreaming Hacker: poor security and unwise choices

Tags: cipher, story, visual, mazes

"Hello, internet. You wanted to see how to breach a secure system? Well, I've picked one out just for you to watch me hack into live. Let's make this happen. Breaching level 1... now!"

[image]

"Ooh, four guard scripts... and looking it over, two glaring security holes. I'll just take the lower of the two and breach security level 2... now!"

[image]

"Wow. An access code wall? Child's play. Starting at the security hole, I have to check every sector and find the access code; should be five digits... And I've got it. Odd, it finishes on the other hole. Anyway, on to security level 3... now!"

[image]

"And an incremented counter to store their login data... traced on level 2 even. I think these guys want to get hacked. Username: admin; Password... Oh, god damn it. I'm done, this server is clearly a trap; give me a minute and I'll pick another one."

---

Alright, there are three question tied up in this puzzle. Each can only be easily solved after solving the one before it; however, if you get stuck, going backward can provide useful clues.

1. Where are the security holes on level 1?
2. What is the access code on level 2?
3. What is the password on level 3?

Comment: I solved this forward, but I'm pretty sure it'd be easy to solve any of these independently (without seeing the other sections).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The security holes are:

> [image]

The access code is:

> [image]
>  **13579**.

The password is:

> given by taking the numbers in each sector in the order from path 2, subtracting them, and converting to A1Z26 to get the string USERNAME ADMIN PASSWORD **SWORDFISH**.

Comment: Now sure how people solve these so quickly..

Comment: My question is why did SWORDFISH alert the hacker that it was a trap?

Comment: @Hypnic Jerk Warning: TV Tropes. [The password is always swordfish](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThePasswordIsAlwaysSwordfish).

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by subtracting in the last step?

Comment: @greenturtle3141: "Walk" along the path. Each number you encounter is larger than the last one. Those differences spell the message.